# LM4890 amplifier and CR1616, how to improve power consumption?

Tags: amplifier, audio, battery-operated, power-consumption, coin-cell

I'm a hobbyst trying to design a simple circuit for amplifying the PWM audio output of an ATTINY85. I'm using an LM4890 (1W amp) and a 1W microspeaker. The problem comes when I supply 3V with a small coin cell, CR1616, which has a small capacity of 60mAh. The circuit works but the battery is drained fast. I checked the datasheet for the LM4890 but I'm still not sure how to calculate the resistor values for using less gain or reducing power consumption. I'm considering to add a regulator for the battery so the sound frequencies can be more stable. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Below is the circuit:

[image]

LM4890 datasheet:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4890.pdf

Comment: The CR1616 is a **tiny** cell, so only if you use this circuit for short periods of time and **power down everything** when not in use (not producing sound) can the battery last a reasonable time. I see that the SHUTDOWN pin of the LM4890 is connected to 3 V so it is **always on**. How do you intend to use this circuit? Does it always need to produce a sound when it is on? If not then use the microcontroller to **shutdown** the amplifier when not used.

Comment: When the circuit is on it will always be outputting sound, constantly, so unfortunately the shutdown has no use for this purpose.

Comment: OK, the amplifier has a quiescent current of about 5 mA, for a 60 mAh battery that means about 12 hours of operation (assuming the microcontroller consumes much less current). Do you get about 12 hours out of a battery? You might get considerably less because 5 mA continuous load is **a lot** for a tiny CR1616. They're not really designed for that.

Comment: At the moment I'm getting only about 2 minutes of operation with a new battery. If I could get 10 minutes that would suffice. I may consider making the design a little bit bigger and use a CR2016 (90mAh) instead, but I'm not sure this will make too much difference.

Comment: It won't. Coin cells are designed for loads in the microamp range, and waste most of their energy in their own internal resistance when drawing such a heavy load. There's no free lunch here -- you need to reset your expectations. Either use a much beefier battery (perhaps a couple of AAA cells?) or reevaluate your power budget, and produce a lot less audio power.

Comment: a AAA cell is too big for the design, the height of components shouldn't exceed 2mm, thus the coin cells. So my only choice may be a lithium battery I believe.

Comment: *I'm getting only about 2 minutes of operation with a new battery* Then obviously the battery is much, much too small for your application. It is not even the 5 mA quiescent current but simply the power that needs to go into the speaker. It is **far** too much for a CR1616. Even other small Lithium cells will not cut it. You **really** need to go to AAA size or larger batteries for the amount of power your application needs.

Comment: I see. I thought the power could be managed through the amp circuit, but the root of the problem is definitely the supply. I will change it to a larger battery then. Thank you.

Comment: Very small lithium-polymer cells _might_ be of use, but make sure you put protection circuitry to avoid breaking them.

Comment: So you have a **one watt** amplifier, and a (60mA-h)(3V) = 180mW-h energy storage device.  We live in a universe where conservation of energy pretty much rules physics.  And you're asking how to generate a given power for longer than the energy you have stored?  What power do you actually need?  If you can get by with much less power out of the amp, then choose a different amp.

Comment: You may want to consider a class D amplifier.  The LM4890 is a linear amp, so it is, at best, a class B device which, in turn, means that it is, at best, 50% efficient -- and that's only at full volume with a nice clean sine wave input.  Lower volumes or higher crest factor inputs will be less efficient.  A class D amp would be bulkier, but would use less (possibly far less) energy for the energy sent to the speaker.  But conservation of energy is still a thing.

Comment: You might want to filter the input...you're making the amplifier work a bit harder than it has to generating ultrasound from the PWM.